# Get value of variable that contains a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable `$path` with a value of `"/home"`.

The variable `$path` is stored in a text file like this:

```
$path/programs
```

In my script, I am getting the line from the text file and setting it to a variable `$ful_path`

Problem: The variable `$full_path` is not getting the value of `$path`

```
echo $full_path
```

Result:

```
$path/programs
```

When I echo `$path/programs` from the command line, I do get `/home/programs`, it's only in the script as a variable it's being treated as a string.

Comment: How do you includes your script? What is the content of text file?

Comment: Text file $path/programs, NOTE that $path is an exported variable

Comment: Are you doing something like `source "filename"` ?

Comment: In the script, I grep “programs” from the file, into a variable. So the line $path/programs becomes the value of the variable.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the code on how you do that? (to be sure, even if I'm pretty sure you can use eval to do that, but there might less risky option there).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something like :

```
export path=/home
echo '$path/programs' > test-file

full_path="$(cat test-file)"
echo "$full_path"
```

You can substitute variables with envsubst :

```
export path=/home
echo '$path/programs' > test-file

full_path="$(cat test-file | envsubst)"
echo "$full_path"
```